# static_cast with unrelated classes

Tags: c++, casting, static-cast

I have following class structure:

[image]

Now I have a `Device` pointer, where I know that it is of type `WiredHeadphone` or `RadioHeadphone`. I need to cast this pointer to `HeadphoneInterface`.

In a perfect world I would just use a dynamic_cast. Unfortunately I am on an embedded platform which does not support dynamic_cast at all. Currently I do this:

```
HeadphoneInterface *GetDeviceAsHeadphone(Device* dev) {
    // use my own type system to identify the actual type and cast accordingly:
    if(dev->GetType() == Type_WiredHeadphone) {
        return static_cast<HeadphoneInterface*>((WiredHeadphone *)dev);
    } else if(dev->GetType() == Type_RadioHeadphone) {
        return static_cast<HeadphoneInterface*>((RadioHeadphone *)dev);
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

This is ugly as hell and not maintainable. There will be more Headphone devices in the future, and I don't want to update this function every time.
Is there a better way to solve this?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Even if you use dynamic cast you're gonna have to update this function in the future for other types since they'll have different methods/members/functionality. If they don't have this kind of difference, then what's the point of having different types? Your casting and returning doesn't do anything on the machine code level, btw. Why are you doing this? The return for both cases is exactly the same.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist with dynamic_cast, the function would simplify to HeadphoneInterface *GetDeviceAsHeadphone(Device* dev) { return dynamic_cast<HeadphoneInterface*>(dev); }.

Comment: You could add a method `getInterfaceType()` to the `Device` class, override this method in your concrete classes and return the appropriate interface type. Then you could write just `if (dev->getInterfaceType() == InterfaceTypes::Headphone) ...`, and then use `reinterpret_cast<>`

Comment: @jwsc Like Rene said. You can implement your own `dynamic_cast`. This is what llvm does btw.

Comment: Note that for `(WiredHeadphone *)dev` cast to work the derived class must derive from `WiredHeadphone` first, otherwise the cast fails/UB at run-time (no compiler error).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a virtual function to `Device` interface that does the (cross) cast to `HeadphoneInterface` for you:

```
struct HeadphoneInterface;

struct Device {
// ...
    virtual HeadphoneInterface* getHeadphoneInterface() noexcept { return 0; }
// ...
};
```

And override the function in `WiredHeadphone` and `RadioHeadphone` to return a non-null pointer to `HeadphoneInterface`:

```
struct WiredHeadphone : WiredDevice, HeadphoneInterface {
    HeadphoneInterface* getHeadphoneInterface() noexcept override { return this; }
};
```

Then `GetDeviceAsHeadphone` becomes:

```
inline HeadphoneInterface* GetDeviceAsHeadphone(Device* dev) noexcept {
    return dev->getHeadphoneInterface();
}
```

Notice that no explicit cast is required here.